Send SMS in the background using Expo React Native on Android
I want to send a SMS in the background using React Native Expo on an android device.
I am using expo-sms and expo-background-fetch.
The problem I have is that the background fetch callback never gets triggered.
It does get registered but it never triggers.
What am I doing wrong?
In app/_layout.tsx
const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = 'background-fetch-sms';
// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

// 1. Define the task by providing a name and the function that should be executed
// Note: This needs to be called in the global scope (e.g outside of your React components)
TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, async () => {
  try {
    const { result } = await SMS.sendSMSAsync(“+1021230213”,”a sample message”);
   return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData;

   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err)
     return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.Failed;

   }

});

async function registerBackgroundFetchAsync() {
  return BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, {
    minimumInterval: 60 * 10, // 10 minutes
    stopOnTerminate: false, // android only,
    startOnBoot: true, // android only
  });
}

export default function RootLayout() {
const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    checkStatusAsync();
  }, []);

  const checkStatusAsync = async () => {
    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    const isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK);
    console.log('Background fetch status:', status);
    setStatus(status);
    setIsRegistered(isRegistered);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus.Available && !isRegistered) {
      registerBackgroundFetchAsync();
    }
  }, [status, isRegistered]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(session?.user.id) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', session.user.id);

    }
  }, [session]);

return (
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
        </Stack>)

}

Is this allowed by expo?
What do you think I’m doing wrong?
